# DatabricksSQL: package.TreeNodeException: execute, tree: ShuffleQueryStage 26, Statistics(sizeInBytes=21.5 MiB, isRuntime=true)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have created 5 temp views from pyspark dataframes to run a  query performing some joins and other operations like aggregation on numerical columns etc.
When I run the query in SSMS, I'm able to get the desired output but when I run the same in Databricks SQL I get the following error.

```
> package.TreeNodeException: execute, tree: ShuffleQueryStage 26,
> Statistics(sizeInBytes=21.5 MiB, isRuntime=true)
> +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Product_Line_Description#333640, _groupingexpression#333910, _groupingexpression#333911, _groupingexpression#333912, _groupingexpression#333913, _groupingexpression#333914, 512), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#568961]    +- *(26) HashAggregate(keys=[Product_Line_Description#333640, _groupingexpression#333910, knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(_groupingexpression#333911))
> AS _groupingexpression#333911, _groupingexpression#333912,
> _groupingexpression#333913, knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(_groupingexpression#333914))
> AS _groupingexpression#333914],
> functions=[partial_sum(Offered_customer#333839) AS sum#333925],
> output=[Product_Line_Description#333640, _groupingexpression#333910,
> _groupingexpression#333911, _groupingexpression#333912, _groupingexpression#333913, _groupingexpression#333914, sum#333925])
>       +- Union
>          :- *(24) HashAggregate(keys=[Product_Line_Description#333640, Region#333832, Date#333834, Product_Group_Name#333638,
> Business_Type_Name#333641], functions=[finalmerge_sum(merge
> sum#333927) AS sum(cast(Offered_customer#333879 as double))#333887],
> output=[Product_Line_Description#333640, Offered_customer#333839,
> _groupingexpression#333910, _groupingexpression#333911, _groupingexpression#333912, _groupingexpression#333913, _groupingexpression#333914])
>          :  +- CustomShuffleReader coalesced
>          :     +- ShuffleQueryStage 23, Statistics(sizeInBytes=17.6 MiB, rowCount=1.62E+5, isRuntime=true)
>          :        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Product_Line_Description#333640, Region#333832,
> Date#333834, Product_Group_Name#333638, Business_Type_Name#333641,
> 512), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#568455]
>          :           +- *(18) HashAggregate(keys=[Product_Line_Description#333640, Region#333832,
> Date#333834, Product_Group_Name#333638, Business_Type_Name#333641],
> functions=[partial_sum(cast(Offered_customer#333879 as double)) AS
> sum#333927], output=[Product_Line_Description#333640, Region#333832,
> Date#333834, Product_Group_Name#333638, Business_Type_Name#333641,
> sum#333927])
>          :              +- Union
>          :                 :- *(16) Project [Product_Line_Description#333640, AMS AS Region#333832,
> cast(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(Offered#333676) -
> promote_precision(Cleared_Count#333683)), DecimalType(38,0), true) as
> string) AS Offered_customer#333879, partition_calendar_date#333687 AS
> Date#333834, Product_Group_Name#333638, Business_Type_Name#333641]
>          :                 :  +- *(16) BroadcastHashJoin [target_virtual_queue#333536], [Resource_Name#333632], Inner,
> BuildRight, false
>          :                 :     :- *(16) Project [Offered#333676, Cleared_Count#333683, partition_calendar_date#333687,
> target_virtual_queue#333536]
>          :                 :     :  +- *(16) BroadcastHashJoin [knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(cast(Resource_Key#333675
> as double)))],
> [knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(cast(queue_resource_key#333533
> as double)))], Inner, BuildRight, false
>          :                 :     :     :- CustomShuffleReader local
>          :                 :     :     :  +- ShuffleQueryStage 0, Statistics(sizeInBytes=285.4 MiB, rowCount=4.16E+6, isRuntime=true)
>          :                 :     :     :     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(cast(Resource_Key#333675
> as double))), 512), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#565246]
>          :                 :     :     :        +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(Resource_Key#333675)
>          :                 :     :     :           +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
>          :                 :     :     :              +- FileScan parquet
> [Resource_Key#333675,Offered#333676,Cleared_Count#333683,partition_calendar_date#333687]
> Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(Resource_Key#333675)], Format:
> Parquet, Location:
> PreparedDeltaFileIndex[abfss://transformed-domain-data@ebproebiadls.dfs.core.windows.net/services...,
> PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(Resource_Key)],
> ReadSchema:
> struct<Resource_Key:decimal(10,0),Offered:decimal(38,0),Cleared_Count:decimal(38,0),partition_cal...
>          :                 :     :     +- BroadcastQueryStage 16, Statistics(sizeInBytes=64.1 MiB, rowCount=3.21E+3, isRuntime=true)
>          :                 :     :        +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(ArrayBuffer(knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(cast(input[0,
> string, true] as double)))),false), [id=#566599]
>          :                 :     :           +- CustomShuffleReader local
>          :                 :     :              +- ShuffleQueryStage 1, Statistics(sizeInBytes=228.4 KiB, rowCount=3.21E+3, isRuntime=true)
>          :                 :     :                 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(cast(queue_resource_key#333533
> as double))), 512), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#565266]
>          :                 :     :                    +- *(2) Project [queue_resource_key#333533, target_virtual_queue#333536]
>          :                 :     :                       +- *(2) Filter ((isnotnull(resource_type_name#333535) AND
> isnotnull(queue_resource_key#333533)) AND
> isnotnull(target_virtual_queue#333536))
>          :                 :     :                          +- *(2) ColumnarToRow
>          :                 :     :                             +- FileScan parquet
> [queue_resource_key#333533,resource_type_name#333535,target_virtual_queue#333536]
> Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(resource_type_name#333535),
> isnotnull(queue_resource_key#333533), isnotnull(target_vir..., Format:
> Parquet, Location:
> InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/innovation-services@ebstgebiadls.dfs.core.windows.net/rr-call-volume-fore...,
> PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(resource_type_name),
> IsNotNull(queue_resource_key), IsNotNull(target_virtual_queue)],
> ReadSchema:
> struct<queue_resource_key:string,resource_type_name:string,target_virtual_queue:string>
>          :                 :     +- BroadcastQueryStage 15, Statistics(sizeInBytes=64.0 MiB, rowCount=312, isRuntime=true)
>          :                 :        +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(ArrayBuffer(input[0, string,
> true]),false), [id=#566096]
>          :                 :           +- CustomShuffleReader local
>          :                 :              +- ShuffleQueryStage 2, Statistics(sizeInBytes=40.5 KiB, rowCount=312, isRuntime=true)
>          :                 :                 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Resource_Name#333632, 512), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS,
> [id=#565292]
>          :                 :                    +- *(3) Project [Resource_Name#333632, Product_Group_Name#333638,
> Product_Line_Description#333640, Business_Type_Name#333641]
>          :                 :                       +- *(3) Filter ((((((((isnotnull(Region_Code#333634) AND
> isnotnull(Forecasting_flag#333645)) AND
> isnotnull(Product_Line_Description#333640)) AND (Region_Code#333634 =
> AMS)) AND (Forecasting_flag#333645 = Yes)) AND NOT
> Contains(Product_Line_Description#333640, LAR)) AND NOT
> Contains(Product_Line_Description#333640, Brazil)) AND NOT
> Contains(Product_Line_Description#333640, MX)) AND
> isnotnull(Resource_Name#333632))
>          :                 :                          +- *(3) ColumnarToRow
>          :                 :                             +- FileScan parquet
> [Resource_Name#333632,Region_Code#333634,Product_Group_Name#333638,Product_Line_Description#333640,Business_Type_Name#333641,Forecasting_flag#333645] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(Region_Code#333634),
> isnotnull(Forecasting_flag#333645), isnotnull(Product_Line_Descri...,
> Format: Parquet, Location:
> InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/innovation-services@ebstgebiadls.dfs.core.windows.net/rr-call-volume-fore...,
> PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(Region_Code),
> IsNotNull(Forecasting_flag), IsNotNull(Product_Line_Description),
> EqualT..., ReadSchema:
> struct<Resource_Name:string,Region_Code:string,Product_Group_Name:string,Product_Line_Description...
>          :                 +- *(17) Project [Product_Line_Description#333591, AMS AS Region#333868,
> Offered_customer#333592, cast(Calendar_Date#333589 as date) AS
> Date#333870, Product_Group_Name#333638, Business_Type_Name#333641]
```

Note: I have read in some forums that the issue could be due to AutoBroadcast and I tried disabling the same with the following code but the issue still persists.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you provide code (operations ) you are using to replicate same at our end

Comment: @SachinTiwari I have added the code. Please check and let me know if you can find the issue

Comment: @AkhileshPothuri please post your sql code